# Can Elasticsearch 1.x Discover Clusters on an IP Range?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have two Elasticsearch clusters set up on AWS using EC2 servers, sat behind a load balancer. I want to configure AWS to start up new instances when the load hits a certain threshold on the load balancer. Currently I have the Elasticsearch instances speaking to each other with the following config in `config/elasticsearch.yml`:

`discover.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.x.x.x","172.x.x.x"]`

Since the new instance will start up on an indeterminable private IP in the subnet, I was wondering if it was possible to point the config at an IP range so that new clusters could be discovered as they start up. Are there security implications to doing this?

If not, is there another way to achieve the same outcome? I am aware that Elasticsearch is meant to handle load balancing and scaling by itself, however this is part of a larger solution and specified in security specifications of my partner on the project.

**The Question**

When hosting Elasticsearch on AWS EC2:

1. Can you set up Elasticsearch discovery to use an IP range?
2. Are there security implications to doing this when using AWS?
3. If not, what is the appropriate way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out myself. For anyone else who happens upon this, here is what I did.

I set up a basic instance with Elasticsearch, Apache and Java installed, and made a simple Elasticsearch startup script so that it would start on system boot.

I set the node name on my ES instances to be `node.name: ${HOSTNAME}` so that each node would be identifiable in the cluster and has a unique name in case I ever need to manually log into the server to check anything.

The big gotcha is that you have to use Elasticsearch's cloud-aws plugin for the relevant version of Elasticsearch that you're using. It can be found [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws)

Using `elasticsearch.yml` you can configure your installations using cloud-aws specific config, you can make it so that ES isn't dependent on an IP address to join a cluster, but can instead discover a cluster based on instance tags, subnets, or anything else that is unique but determinable about your new instances in AWS.

I found [this](http://chrissimpson.co.uk/using-elasticsearch-on-amazon-ec2.html) article very helpful. The main points from the article that are helpful are below.

**AWS IAM Role**
An IAM role needs to be set up and allocated to your new instances to allow them to communicate with AWS and check the new instances for certain values. The role should have these permissions.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeRegions",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
```

**Elasticsearch config**
After installing cloud-aws, you will be able to use new config in your elasticsearch.yml file. First, remove `discover.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:` as this is no longer needed. The most basic setup to get this to work is:

```
cloud:
    aws:
        access_key: <YOUR AWS KEY>
        secret_key: <YOUR AWS SECRET>
discovery:
    type: ec2
```

But a more tuned configuration is below. It will look for instances with a tag of `esdiscovery:enabled`:

```
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
discovery.ec2.tag.esdiscovery: enabled
cloud:
    aws:
        access_key: <YOUR AWS KEY>
        secret_key: <YOUR AWS SECRET>
    region: <YOUR AWS REGION>
discovery:
    type: ec2
```

If you're using EU West, then you need to replace the region with the following config:

```
cloud:
    aws:
        ec2:
            endpoint: ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
```